# Modified existing XML file using Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml

I have one XML file in resources. I want to modify that XML file.

Want to attach image to it,insert data(String, Integer, float) into it and insert values in specific nodes.

How can I manage all these tasks in objectiveC?
(My XML file is a actually a converted file from Excel. So modifying this file will result me a new Excel file.)

If my question is not clear, please ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For writing xml you can use [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/xmltutorial.pdf). It is a **DOM based XMLParser**.

Also you can use [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) for this.

Here is a simple [tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/) for TouchXML.